# How could I draw a picture by connecting stars between them?

Tags: plotting, graphics, image-processing, image, neural-networks

My idea is to try to make a program which would be able to trace a given picture in the sky, by simply connecting stars. Therefore, I have two questions.

1. Is it possible to convert the product of an EdgeDetect[] to a graph of coordinates (the plotted points would be the white pixels ?) I'm already pretty confident I'll manage this part.
2. Is it possible, once I will have the graph, to find a function (or make one), which would find the closest approximation in the sky to the given graph ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! You've posted an interesting question – however, please edit the question and include all relevant information: An example of the image, the code you are using, expected output etc.

Comment: V13.2 added new astronomical computation [functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn132#:~:text=coefficient%20linear%20DEs-,Astronomy,-Astro%20Computation%20%C2%BB) that you might find useful. A [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P894i_9BRf8) by the developers explaining the new features.